# Teenage boy on an alien planet

Tags: story-identification, aliens

When I was between Jr. high and high school (It was probably published between 1998 and 2006 at the latest) I read a book but I can't seem to remember the name.

It had a teenage boy on an alien planet (I don't remember how he got there) and it starts with him trying to survive on his own. He finds an alien girl, or she finds him, and she takes him to her tribe or something, and they basically help him survive there and he eventually ends up marrying the girl after he earned like his own place among them.

I'm reasonably sure it was in the 'Young Adult' book section.

Comment: You'd probably want to add actual dates to the question, since we don'T know when you went to high school.

Comment: This is basically the plot of Avatar, Dances with Wolves, Ferngully, etc etc etc. Since it fits at least three properties off the top of my head, I'm voting to close as too broad unless you can suggest something to distinguish it. Have a look through the checklists [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if that helps.

Comment: No, the kid was the only human on that planet. Avatar has way more humans besides some kid. Dances with Wolves and Ferngully are both fantasy, not sci-fi.

Comment: What @Valorum means, is that there are many books with this basic premise. Unless you can remember specific details, this book will be impossible to find. Welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack, by the way. Have you taken the [tour] yet?

Comment: @Kristi - What I'm trying to drive at is that you've listed three extremely common sci-fi novel tropes; [Trapped in another world](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TrappedInAnotherWorld), [Interspecies Romance](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InterspeciesRomance) and [Of The People](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OfThePeople) but not much else. Something that will distinguish it (such as the name of a character, a memorable scene, a notable incident, a snippet of dialogue, etc etc) will take this from the general to the specific.

Comment: Well, there is The Transall Saga by Gary Paulsen, 1998. He thinks he's on an alien planet, and the people are humanoid. He may have married the girl (named Megaan) after joining them. I know he asks, at least.